# My laptop won't turn on

Tags: boot, hardware-failure

My laptops' battery is dead, I used to use it with the AC adapter only (without battery).

Suddenly it wouldn't start anymore; I gave it to a service center for repairs. Then it started and worked for 2-3 days, but again it fails to boot. This is the 3rd time.

Background: It was affected by malware and adware so I formatted it. I changed the adapter. The service people said some part was replaced. I
use torrent a lot.

What may be the reason and the solution?

Comment: Ask the service center people which part got replaced. They also should be able to answer your question better than we can - we don't see the laptop.

Comment: But they aslo checked 3 times now...it works for 2 days when comes from service center then again same problem can malware cause these type of issue...??

Answer (score -1):

If it works for 2-3 days each time after it comes from repair, as you say, then I assume they probably are just reinstalling the OS. I've faced this exact issue before, formatted the drive with a clean Windows installation, and it crapped out after a day or two.

The problem in my case was a dying HDD, so I suggest you try using your computer with another working HDD (not necessarily new) and see how that goes. You might also want to check your existing drive's condition with any SMART analysis software, like CrystalDiskInfo.